# Installing rEFIt or rEFInd without OSX

Tags: macos, boot, refit

After a bout installing Ubuntu on my MacMini I am now left with GRUB and no installation disk for OSX 10.8

I can boot to Ubuntu 13.04 and I have a Windows machine. I need a way to get into OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by luck. I dropped to a GRUB command (press `C` on start up GRUB screen) and then `exit` to exit the GRUB menu. Once exited, you will see the rEFIt menu. This will allow you to boot back to OSX and clean up GRUB (it is no longer needed).